# RegEx: Negated lookahead a back reference many times

Tags: regex

How do we lookahead until there is no back reference of a character in RegEx?

Given:

> We are looking for phrases within quotes and it can be multiline "check we have a return here
>    but this line is still part of previous one 'a' string".
>
> It breaks once we have another 'testing with single quotes "surrounding" double quotes';

How do we look for double quotes and single quotes once they close themselves?

I tried this pattern, but it's not working:

```
/(['"])[^$1]+\1/g
```

[Look here](https://regex101.com/r/B43eci/4)

Comment: `/(['"])(?:\\[^]|(?!\1)[^\\])*?\1/g`

Comment: what's `\\ ` at the beginning of `(?:..`?

Comment: That is a ``\``. `\\[^]` matches any escape sequence. Do you have escape sequences in the strings you want to match?

Comment: Why it bypasses new line, it's very strange, would you send me a link to its docs?

Comment: If you don't have any escaped characters just use [`'[^']+'|"[^"]+"`](https://regex101.com/r/QhL42m/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your strings have no escape sequences, it is as easy as using a [**tempered greedy token**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970) like

```
/(['"])(?:(?!\1)[\s\S])+\1/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wWIzXK/1/). The `(?:(?!\1)[\s\S])+` matches any symbol (`[\s\S]`) that is not the value captured into Group 1 (either `'` or `"`). To also match `""` or `''`, replace the `+`  (1 or more occurrences) with `*` quantifier (0 or more occurrences).

If you may have escape sequences, you may use

```
/(['"])(?:\\[\s\S]|(?!\1)[^\\])*?\1/g
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/wWIzXK/3).

See the pattern details:

- `(['"])` - Group 1 capturing a `'` or `"`
- `(?:\\[^]|(?!\1)[^\\])*?` - 0+ (but as few as possible) occurrences of

  - `\\[^]` - any escape sequence
  - `|` - or
  - `(?!\1)[^\\]` - any char other than `\` and the one captured into Group 1
- `\1` - the value kept in Group 1.

NOTE: `[\s\S]` in JS matches any char including line break chars. A JS only construct that matches all chars is `[^]` and is preferable from the performance point of view, but is not advised as it is not supported in other regex flavors (i.e. it is not portable).

Comment: The `[^\\]` is a negated character class that matches any char but ``\``. It is necessary to avoid matching it in the second alternative branch because the first one, `\\[\s\S]`, caters for that. A standalone ``\`` is not expected in a C string literal.